# .jar File made from Eclipse won't run

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a single class for an Applet I made, and I have been trying to make it into a .jar file. In Eclipse, I right click on the folder -> Export -> Java-> Jar File->Finish. When it finishes, it says "Exported with compile warnings: FirstApplet/src/ScoreCountingApplet.java". When I click it, it won't do anything, and it is completely unresponsive. I even checked the MF file and made sure that I added in the "Main-Class: ScoreCountingApplet" line to the Manifest. I have no idea how to make it work. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Note: Also, if I try to compile with "javac" in the Command Prompt, it says something to the effect of "javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Comment: What happens when you run `java -jar filename.jar` from the command line?

Comment: It says "Error: unable to access jarfile ScoreCountingApplet.jar"

Comment: you need to run it from the directory where you placed the jar file

Comment: So, I put the .jar file to my desktop (as in after eclipse makes it, that's where it appears), and when I double click it, it won't do anything, regardless of when I change the Manifest. Are you saying to put the jar file in the same place as the original .Java file?

Comment: The fact that "javac is not recognized" means that you have only installed the JRE.  If you install a JDK, you'll get javac.

Answer (score 1):

Applets use to run  a HTML file, on a browser or Appletviewer tool.

Also you have the option or kind of trick to embed a Panel/Applet into a Frame/JFrame,

If the second one is not your case I am not sure if there is a way that your Applet/Jar is going to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Export as Runnable Jar."

Comment: That tells me to choose a .java file to "launch configuration", and for some reason my Applets won't show up in the drop down menu, only text based applications show up.